# Function breaks chart.js

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to insert my chart.js into a Drupal page.
Here is the fully functional fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vy0yhd6m/80/

When I enter that into a basic page content item in Drupal, the chart will not display.
However, if I remove `scaleLabel()`, it works and displays perfectly on the Drupal page. For some reason, adding that function in the Full HTML content item makes the chart disappear, even though it works perfectly in the above JS Fiddle.

```
scaleLabel: function(label){return  ' $' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
```

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: What text filters are enabled on the "Full HTML" format? "Full HTML" doesn't mean that your content isn't being transformed by some kind of text or sanitization filter.

Comment: Convert URLs into links, Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>), and Correct faulty and chopped off HTML. Turning these filters off did not make an impact. In the source code of the page, I see that my JavaScript is in there unaltered. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized I was using an outdated version of Chart.js (from an old production site).
I just updated to the latest version, and now all is well with the world.

Thanks.